# woocommerce_order_status_completed not triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to write a custom plugin that does some action after woocommerce order is completed, but I can't get this hook to work. I can see this question asked many times.

Like here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134463/woocommerce-order-status-completed-action-hook-not-working

Here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce_order_status_completed-is-not-working

And here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce_order_status_completed-action-hook-not-working

But I cannot help myself with answers that these guys received.

I tried to add the action a few different ways:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func');

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this,'ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func'), 10, 1);

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array(&$this,'ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func'), 10, 1);
```

Also tried with a class:

```
class IKHooks {
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this,'ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func'), 10, 1);
    }

    public function ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func( $order_id ) {

    }
}
```

I even tried to put the action outside of the class:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array(IKHooks,'ikwoocommerceorderstatuscompleted_func'), 10, 1);
```

None of these examples work. :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the following steps before calling your hook.

1. Check if order completion email is sent.
2. Hook is properly registered in plugin file or theme `functions.php`

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed','callback_function_name' );

function callback_function_name(){
  global $wp_filter;
  print_r($wp_filter);
  exit;
}
```

Check if the name of your callback function is in the hook array:

```
[woocommerce_order_status_completed] => Array
    (
        [10] => Array
            (
                [wc_paying_customer] => Array
                    (
                        [function] => wc_paying_customer
                        [accepted_args] => 1
                    )

                [wc_downloadable_product_permissions] => Array
                    (
                        [function] => wc_downloadable_product_permissions
                        [accepted_args] => 1
                    )

                [callback_function_name] => Array
                    (
                        [function] => callback_function_name
                        [accepted_args] => 3
                    )

            )

    )
```

If you find it then everything is ok, it means that probably there's an issue with your theme or `functions.php` file. Check for the hook or callback function in your files and then look for `remove_action` or `remove_all_actions` that's probably what's preventing your hook from being called.

You can also check in this way

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'callback_function_name', 1);
```

Change the priority of your hook from 10 to 1 so it is called first than any other action or hook.

Comment: Thanks. I must try this tomorrow.

Comment: Can I ask, how this helped for you? My actions aren't firing, even though they are in in `$wp_filter`

Comment: You can check before execute any wordpress action and filter. What is available your registered hook and callback function.

print_r($wp_filter);  // same as code to check above answer.
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed')

Comment: @user5200704 On my website, it seems `woocommerce_order_status_completed` is not firing when a  user places and completes an order. But if I go to the backend and manually change an order from "on hold" to "completed" , it will fire. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 14):

You can use this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'your_function', 99, 4 );
```

And the function will look like

```
function your_function( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if( $new_status == "completed" ) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. All the other `woocommerce_order_status_*` actions do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue earlier and solved it as:

Following code update the order status as `completed`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'your_wc_autocomplete_order' );

function your_wc_autocomplete_order( $order_id ) {

 if ( ! $order_id ) {
   return;
 }

 $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

 $order->update_status( 'completed' );

}
```

Once order is completed, if you want to do something, see the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','payment_complete');

function payment_complete($order_id)
{
   //global $items;
   //$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
   // do something ...
}
```

Comment: This was my issue. The reason woocommerce_order_status_completed wasn't firing was because the order wasn't completed. It was in "pending" state until I marked in the admin backend as completed. Your code fixes that by marking it as completed automatically upon payment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### **2024 Update**

Use `wc_get_logger()` instead of functions like `var_export` or `print_r` because they may output content in non visible areas, like at the top of the html document or in an ajax response.

```
function your_function( $order_id ){
    wc_get_logger()->debug(sprintf('Order status changed to completed: %s', $order_id));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_function');
```

---

**Old response**

`woocommerce_order_status_changed` and `woocommerce_order_status_completed` actually work for me. After struggling for 2 days i realized that you just can't var_dump or var_export or print_r or whatever in the admin panel, it just won't work.

So if you are a newbie like me and thought those actions weren't working, just try triggering another action like sending a mail for example.

This code works:

```
function your_function( $order_id ){
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $to_email = 'testing_mail@sample.com';
    $payment = $order->get_payment_method_title();
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <Your_site_mail@address.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', $payment, $headers );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_function');
```

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: This simple trick helped me pinpoint the issue with my code. +1

Comment: Is it really true that var_dump, var_export, print_r, etc... cannot be used in the WP admin panel?

Comment: @MikeWeir well, technically you can. It will appear at the beginning of the document and will be visible only when inspecting html elements. The real way to solve this is using WC's logger: `wc_get_logger()->debug('....');`

Answer (score 1):

Try using action hook `woocommerce_order_status_changed`. 
It takes 4 parameters. **order id**, **old status** **new status** and **order**. Further code reference [HERE](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#2284)

This may not be exactly suitable to your requirement, but seems to be worth of an alternative.

Comment: I think this actually gets triggered. But I only get one call with $old_status "pending" and $new_status "on-hold" although I did make a payment via paypal and order should be completed. :(

Comment: I've just noticed that all orders in a database have status "wc-on-hold". Why is that? Is there something wrong in woocommerce?

Comment: Oh.. I've just realized that you have to manually 'complete' the order in the admin panel. But for some reason in my case the hook doesn't get triggered when I click Complete action... This is strange. On every step I get some behaviour that is not what's expected..

Comment: You are right. You need to manually 'complete' the order in admin panel. Just for your reference, if you want check the payment complete action, you can use action hook `woocommerce_payment_complete`.

Comment: woocommerce_payment_complete is also ignored. WHAT IS HAPPENING TO ME?!?! :(

Comment: I've currently got woocommerce_payment_complete wokring, but all the woocommerce_order_status_* doing absolutley nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after this guy. `woocommerce_payment_complete`

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    error_log( "Payment has been received for order $order_id", 0 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete' );
```

Comment: This was months ago but I remember that I was also trying this one with no success. And I have already accepted the correct answer..