# woocommerce_order_status_changed not working in Order Details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this simple hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'function_test', 10, 3);

function function_test($id, $status_transition_from, $status_transition_to ) {
     error_log("¡Done!", 0);
}
```

The problem is that at this point, when I change the status in the order details but is not triggered.

[image]

I have been searching, but is not working anyway.

Here, [woocommerce_order_status_completed not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315825/woocommerce-order-status-completed-not-triggered/36373711), the user user5200704 comments that the method must appear in wp_filter.

This is right, my wp_filter at that point is:

```
[woocommerce_order_status_changed] => WP_Hook Object ( [callbacks] => Array ( [10] => Array ( [function_test] => Array ( [function] => function_test [accepted_args] => 3 ) ) )
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook works fine and is triggered each time when order status change using the methods `update_status()`, 
 `set status()` and `save()`  via the method `status_transition()`…

Comment: When I change the status, after I save the product. And is not triggering. Is that what you are telling me?

Comment: Can you show all your real related code in your question, as your actual pseudo code isn't useful… Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers"*.

Comment: Thanks, but all the related code is on. The error log is empty and that function is in the functions.php file.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Yes, with this hook `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_cancelled_verify', 20, 1 );` it was not logging anything but it was running the code. Try with print_r

Comment: i have same problem after update it stopped  working

Comment: I remember this project. After read documentation, the only way it could be done is with the thank yoy page hook. Order status was bugged. At least in that version.