# Woocommerce action `woocommerce_order_status_completed` not executing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a problem as I am not a woocommerce developer. The client wants to make a product out of stock once the order is completed (and payment received).

I added an action in `functions.php`

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'set_product_out_of_stock', 10, 1 );
 
function set_product_out_of_stock( $order_id ) {
       error_log( "This is a test:  set product out of stock $order_id ^^", 0 );
    //if ( 'completed' == $order_status) {
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $items = $order->get_items();
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                $status = 'outofstock';
                update_post_meta($item['item_id'], '_stock', 0);
                update_post_meta( $item['item_id'], '_stock_status', wc_clean( $status ) );
                wp_set_post_terms($item['item_id'], 'outofstock', 'product_visibility', true );
            }
    // }
 
}
```

The problem is that this action is not even triggered, The error_log doesn't show in the logs.. what may be the issue?

The website uses `woocommerce v 4.7` .

Thank you !

Comment: [woocommerce_order_status_completed not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315825/woocommerce-order-status-completed-not-triggered) --

Comment: Thank you , I will check it out.